# ActionController::UnknownFormat in UsersController#show_friend

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a friend btn. Instead of generating a friendship controller, I chose to add actions under users' resources to pass data into the friendship table. The strange thing is after I've set up routes and added 'show_friend' method in my user controller, the links in my views can't direct me to display the partial template on my user.show page. It noted this error:

[ActionController::UnknownFormat in UsersController#show_friend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doZpf.png)

I have done this in the same way with my other actions: show_reply/show_draft/show_collect, so I don't quite understand why this isn't working.

This is my first question posted here. Please let me know if I didn't put it right.
([my github if needed...](https://github.com/jealic/dojo/tree/max-friend))

routes.rb

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get :show_reply
    get :show_draft
    get :show_collect
    get :show_friend

    post :invite_friend
    post :accept_friend
    post :ignore_friend
  end
end
```

user_controller.rb

```
def show_friend
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

views/users/show.html.erb

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <%= link_to "My Friends", show_friend_user_path(@user), class: "nav-link #{'active' if action?('show_friend')}" %>
</li>

#...left out...

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <% if action?('show_draft') %>
      <%= render partial: 'drafts' %>
    <% elsif action?('show_reply') %>
      <%= render partial: 'replies' %>
    <% elsif action?('show_collect') %>
      <%= render partial: 'collection' %>
    <% elsif action?('show_friend') %>
      <%= render partial: 'friends' %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render partial: 'posts' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

views/users/_friends.html.erb

```
<div class="big-yellow-light">
  <h1>Here's the FRIENDSHIP info</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Your action is `show_friend`, so when Rails process it it renders a template `show_friend.html.erb` (unless another template is specified, but you don't specify any). Can you show your `show_friend.html.erb` ?

Comment: I didn't prepare a `show_friend.html.erb` is because I want it to render a partial :`_friends.html.erb` in my post show page. But yes, after I added a new show_friend.html.erb under my users folder, the connection works fine. And I just suddenly found the key: In my `def show_friend` I had to add this line: `render :show`. That makes the difference! Thanks for your help! The answer just hits me...